# Do i need to create Mule connector or i can use Hosted API?

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, mule, mule-studio

I have a scenario in which i need to sync data from salesforce, zendesk, marketo or slack to my Web Application.

So, i researched that i can use Mulesoft connectors for this scenario. also there are many examples available to sync data between these apps, but i need to sync data from these apps to my Web App.

I tried to create API, but i am confused how to use connectors with own API.

So, my question is that do i need to create my own connector or i can simple use HTTP connector to sync data.

Answer (score 1):

@Virendra yadav,

This can be done in two ways:

a. Either you consume APIs of all the applications directly in your web app. 
b. Create APIs in Mule which will internally call slack/salesforce APIs and will give you the result.
Your APIs will be something like this:
Take request -> call slack/salesforce/marketo -> transform and send it to your webapp.

Just to add slack/salesforce are capable of exposing data through there own API's.

Regards,
Suyog.

Answer (score 0):

The API that you want to use may or may not have an connector, but you can use the HTTP connector for connecting to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple HTTP connector to consume your RestAPI and then use transformer to convert your data to appropriate format

Comment: can you provide and reference link where i can start learning